# filter bad json values from json in a memory efficient way

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, nodejs-stream, stream-json

We have some bad json we're trying to parse. Unfortunately it isn't valid json as it returns unquoted `NaN`'s in the payload.

We are switching from the long deprecated `request` library to `axios`. This seems to have doubled our memory usage of our current way of fixing this payload, but our environment is memory constrained. The file is 19MB, our constraint is 50MB. I presume that something to do with the regex's/parse is making yet another copy of the json in memory,
in addition to the parsing that `axios` is trying to do.

We are using a wrapper around axios so interfacing directly with it is limited. I'd have to reimplement parts of the wrapper to get to it and it's an external internal library.

I know the key's we're trying to keep, so just discarding the rest of the structure instead of dealing with the NaN is actually preferable.

The structure we want, looks like `DataUsages[]`

```
export interface DataUsages {
    dataUsageId: string;
    dataUsageName: string;
}
```

The structure we're getting has additional items in the objects in the array, we don't care about `"dataUsageDownstreamUsages"` at all, and that key could and is being discarded`

```json
[
  {
    "dataUsageId": "42",
    "dataUsageName": "myname",
    "dataUsageDownstreamUsages": [NaN]
  }
]
```

#### current

This is our current method

```
      const reg1 = /\[NaN]|NaN/gm
      const parsed: EDMDataUsages[] = JSON.parse(
        requireNonNullish(response.body, 'body').replace(reg1, '""').replace(/NAN/gm, ''),
      )
```

#### stream-json

Right now I'm looking at using [`stream-json`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json) for this.

If I use parser it bails, presumably when it reach's a `NaN`. So I'm looking at the `disassembler` but I don't understand how to do it with that.

```
  const read = new Readable()
  read.push(requireNonNullish(response.body, 'body'))
  read.push(null)

  const pipeline = chain([read, disassembler(), pick({ filter: 'data' }), data => this.log.trace('data', data)])
  pipeline.on('data', data => this.log.trace('filter', data))
```

obviously this code is not complete.

Other libraries are acceptable. Please provide a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

ok first of all lets create a fake data

```
function genreateFakeData() {
    const payload = { res: [] }
    const mock = {
        "dataUsageId": "42",
        "dataUsageName": "myname",
        "dataUsageDownstreamUsages": [NaN]
    }
    let totalFileSize = 0;
    const fileSize = 19;
    const SIZE_IN_BYTES = JSON.stringify(mock).length;
    const SIZE_IN_MB = SIZE_IN_BYTES / 1024 / 1024;

    while (totalFileSize < fileSize) {
        totalFileSize += SIZE_IN_MB;
        payload.res.push(mock);
    }
    fs.appendFileSync('fake.json', JSON.stringify(payload));
}
```

then lets test this is the right size of the file

```
> ls -ltrh | grep fake
-rw-r--r--   1 naor.tedgi  staff    19M Jun 15 09:34 fake.json
```

let's run the node app under the heap constraint and mutate the original response

`node --max-old-space-size=50 index.js`

index.js

```
const stream = require('stream');
const fs = require('fs');
const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('fake.json',{encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'}));
data.res.forEach(entry=>{
    delete entry.dataUsageDownstreamUsages
})
console.log(data)
```